# Necessary and sufficient conditions (1) rv to density function (2) distribution to rv

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

(1) Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability measure space and $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a random variable. Let $P_X,~F_X$ denote the probability measure, pdf induced by $X$, respectively. Under which conditions on X (or $P_X$, $F_X$) does X admit a density function. i.e. an integrable function $f$ such that $\displaystyle P(X\in B)=P_X(B)=\int_Bf(x)dx,~B\in \mathcal{B}$?

PS. I am aware of the Radon - Nikodym theorem, introducing conditions under which a (probability) measure generally admits a density function, but do they change when dealing with a probability measure induced $P_X$ by a rv $X$ (and how)?

(2) Let $F$ be a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$. Under which conditions, if any, does there exist a random variable X from some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, such that $F=F_X$, i.e. $F$ is the pdf induced by X?

Thanks a lot in advance for the help!

Comment: 1) A pdf of a r.v. is the R-N derivative of the induced measure w.r.t some base measure (e.g. Lebesgue in continuous case).

2) It's not clear what is $F$ here. Is it a function corresponding to some Borel measure?

Comment: 2) If $F$ is a CDF, you can take $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})=(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, $X(\omega)=\omega$ and $P$ is such that $P(X\in (a,b])=F(b)-F(a)$.